# Variables scope in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I created a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web Application project using Visual Studio 2019 with the "Web Application" template. Everything works as expected, I can build and run the application without any issue.

Then I started editing the `_Layout.cshtml` file. This snippet builds fine:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication1</title>
</head>
<body>
    @{ string foo = (string)ViewData["foo"]; }
    @if (foo == "bar")
    {
        <div>test</div>
    }
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

This one doesn't build:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication1</title>
    @{ string foo = (string)ViewData["foo"]; }
</head>
<body>
    @if (foo == "bar")
    {
        <div>test</div>
    }
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Building the solution with the 2nd snippet results in the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: WebApplication1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\...\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Pages\Shared\_Layout.cshtml(9,10,9,13): error CS0103: The name 'foo' does not exist in the current context
1>Done building project "WebApplication1.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

Are Razor Pages variables scoped to their declaring HTML tag? If so, why does the intellisense not show any error when I declare the variable in an unreachable scope and allows me to navigate to the variable definition using the F12 key?

Comment: I just ran into the very same problem - if you managed to solve it, would you mind posting the solution as an answer?

Comment: @Kathi It looks like the issue occurs only when the variable is declared in the `<head>` tag and is referenced in the `<body>` tag. So I just moved the declaration at the beginning of the `<body>` tag, and everything compiled again. It even works when the variable is declared in a non-parent tag, as long as it's not in the `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but the issue only occurs when the variable is declared in the `<head>` tag. So as a workaround, I just moved the declaration in the `<body>` tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication1</title>
</head>
<body>
    @{ string foo = (string)ViewData["foo"]; }
    @if (foo == "bar")
    {
        <div>test</div>
    }
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Just to clarify, it even works when the variable is not declared in a parent node, so the original issue is not related to DOM hierarchy, but rather to a specific behavior of the compiler with the head section:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    @{ string foo = (string)ViewData["foo"]; }
    </div>
    <div>
    @if (foo == "bar")
    {
        <div>test</div>
    }
    </div>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Spent hours to figure out what was the issue. Thanks a lot.  :-)

Answer (score -1):

I used your _Layout.cshtml view code, and the same error as yours occurred during the startup of VS, and then the following error was reported on the page:

[image]

By default, every layout must call RenderBody. Wherever the call to RenderBody is placed, the contents of the view will be rendered.After you add it, you can start the project normally.

In addition to the problem of Razor variables, you only need to use @{} to declare variables in the block. Then, you can use the variable anywhere in the view.

Comment: As mentionned in the question, I did not include all the original content in the snippet for brevity. The `RenderBody` call is performed in my layout. In fact I did not delete any single line of code from the original layout generated by Visual Studio, I only added the lines shown in the snippet. Note also that `@{}` is used in the variable declaration.